# How to Exipre password after exipryDate in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application how can i exipre the password after exiprydate and ask the user to change the password...can u please me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an expiration date to work with, you can simply compare the current date with the expiration date and if the difference exceeds your allowable range of time, you prompt the user to change their password.

Comment: Thank you for replying..suppose the exipry date is 90 days,but if the user update the password after 25 days.the exipry date should be 90 days only...

Comment: you need to track the last time the password was changed. So when they change the password, store the current date so you can compare against that.

Comment: How about you give it the good old "college try" and come back with questions and code so that we can HELP you. No one here is interested in doing it FOR you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to your login process: if the password expiry date is in the past, redirect the user to a page where he/she can change the password. If it has not expired, login as usual.